# Writing jQuery plugin, where to set $.extend to be accessible on other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm learning to write some jQuery plugin, before this is the structure that I'm using:

```
!(function($){
    var defaults = {
        target: ''
    };

    $.fn.myplugin = function(options){
        var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options)  
               return this.each(function(){ 
                  //
               });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Now, I am looking to apply some update method for my plugin and so I've checked out some plugins on github. And this is the structure that works very well for me:

```
!(function($){
    var defaults = {
        target: ''
    },
    build = function(){
    },
    methods = {
        init: function(options){
            var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options)
        },
        update: function(){
        }
    };

    $.fn.myplugin = function(method){
        if(methods[method]){
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }else if(typeof method === 'object' || !method){
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }else{
            $.error('error message');
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

However `$.extend` is declared on the `init` function and I'm having trouble with accessing for example my `settings.target` value on my other functions like `build`. I can only access it by calling the function `build` inside `init` and passing an argument like so (which is an awful thing to do) :

```
init: function(options){
     var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options)
     build(settings.target);
}
```

I need to move the `$.extend({}, defaults, options)` somewhere else for me to access it on functions outside `init`. Please help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Store your `settings` on element using `.data()` jQuery function.

```
methods = {
    init: function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this.data('settings', settings);
    },
    update: function(){
        var settings = this.data('settings');

    }
};
```

More complete code:

```
!(function($){
   var defaults = {
       target: ''
   },
   build = function(settings){
      // use settings.target here
   },
   methods = {
       init: function(options){
           var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options)
           this.data('settings', settings);
       },
       update: function(){
          var settings = this.data('settings');
          build(settings);
       }
   };

   $.fn.myplugin = function(method){
       if(methods[method]){
           return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
       }else if(typeof method === 'object' || !method){
           return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
       }else{
           $.error('error message');
       }
   }})(jQuery);
```

Use this plugin:

```
$(element).myplugin();
$(element).myplugin('update');
```

Comment: when I call on `$(element).myplugin('update')` I got an error because settings is still `undefined` - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`.

Comment: in first you should call `$(element).myplugin()` then `$(element).myplugin('update')`